# Someone's / something's privilege against someone / something else

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Imagine two friends are talking to each other about a rival company which is competing one of these two (as the owner of a big company) for a big project to win the lowest bid. The guy who is the owner of the company is worried a lot and the other one is going to make his advantages bold and express his sympathy in that way. I have no idea how to phrase it like a native speaker. I just can translate what comes through my mind to English. Please let me know if it sounds natural to you? If not, please let me know how a native speaker would say it:

> - Don't worry; your privilege (in front of / against) him is your education degree / financial (status / conditions) / etc.

Comment: "But you have a degree and he doesn't." "But you have more (financial) resources than they do." Is this what you had been looking for? Because you had said that this is between two friends, I made the phrasing very informal and direct. If you want something more similar to your construction, I would say, "Your advantages over him include your degree and your (financial) resources."

Comment: Replace 'your privilege (in front of/ against) him is' in your example sentence with 'your advantage in comparison to him is'.

Answer (score 4):

'Privilege' is the wrong word to use here; use 'advantage' instead, and usually one would say 'to have an advantage over someone'.

So it would go something like this: "Don't worry, you have an advantage over him because you have [a better degree / more money / etc.]"

You could also phrase it like: "Don't worry, your [superior degree / better financial status / etc.] gives you an advantage over him."

Comment: Would it be possible to say: "...**your advantage over him is**..."@neotryte

Comment: Yes that would also work

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Upper hand](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/upper-hand) too.

So we paraphrase it as:
***"Don't worry, with your education degrees or financial status, you [gain the upper hand"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/get-gain-the-upper-hand).***

Yes, it is a [synonym of 'advantage'](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/upper+hand). I just thought you might want to consider as '*privilege* is not as appropriate.